# how to inserting data after completion of inserting and updating the data

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am developing one application. In that iam facing the problem at inserting the data into database. First insert and update will be performed very well. After updating if i want to perform insert operation then app will be crashed. My code for inserting and updating were like below

```
+(BOOL)update:(CalendarInfo*)clInfo
{
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ABC set A = '%@' where B =%d and C=%d",clInfo.a,clInfo.b,clInfo.c]; 
    sqlite3_stmt *stStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &stStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(SQLITE_DONE == sqlite3_step(stStatement))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            NSLog(@"updation  Successful");
    }
    return 0;
}

+(BOOL)insert:(CalendarInfo*)clInfo{

    sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;
    sqlite3 *contactDB;
    NSArray *docPathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *destPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/example.sqlite",[docPathArr objectAtIndex:0]];

    if (sqlite3_open([destPath UTF8String], &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *query2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT  INTO ABC(C,B,A) VALUES(%d,%d,'%@')",clInfo.c,clInfo.b, clInfo.a];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,  [query2 UTF8String], -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        NSLog(@"Insertion Successful");

    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);

    return 0;
}
```

So please tell me how to solve my problem.

Comment: which line of code is actually crashing?

Comment: if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
In this loop second line will be crashed

Comment: when it crashes, is there an error in the console?  Does it crash on the `sqlite3_step` or the `sqlite3_errmsg` line (which I think is the "second line" of your last comment)?

Comment: In sqlite3_errmsg app will be crashed.And error is "Assertion failure in +[Database insert]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited code you've posted, I think the answer has to do with that you have ***two*** different `sqlite3` instances here.  Was this intentional?

You call `sqlite3_open([destPath UTF8String], &contactDB);`

and then attempt to get an error result off another `sqlite` instance:

```
sqlite3_errmsg(database)
```

Either use `database` or `contactDB` and you should be all set.

Comment: and why if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
  was satisfied.If that was not satisfied then problem will be solved.